# tensorflow C++ equivalent of tf.trainable_variables()?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

My goal is to get a list of names with all the trainable variables from the C++ API. In Python this would be down with tf.trainable_variables().

So far I tried this approach.
I have a tensorflow::GraphDef object and I can see all nodes that have been created like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < graphDef.node_size(); i++) {
    graphDef.node(i).PrintDebugString();
}
```

which is great. Some of those nodes refer to trainable variables, but I don't know how do I get that information / or if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is not available in the [`GraphDef`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphDef) object. [`tf.trainable_variables`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables) just returns the graph collection with key [`tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys#TRAINABLE_VARIABLES), but graph collections are not saved to the [`GraphDef`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphDef), only to the [`MetaGraphDef`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/MetaGraphDef) (see [Exporting and Importing a MetaGraph](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/meta_graph)). If you want to access trainable variables in a saved graph from C++, you have to either export and import the MetaGraph instead or, maybe, use a consistent naming scheme to differentiate them.

Note, by the way, that graph collections will be deprecated in TensorFlow 2.x. See [Deprecating collections](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180905-deprecate-collections.md) for more information.